# AppleScript Button to open an other Window

Tags: xcode, window, applescript

my idea is to make a simple program with one Buttons in AppleScript (Xcode).

When you press the button, a new window should open.

```
on button_(sender)
    --open second window
end button_
```

But how I can make this?

Thanks to you an stay health!

Comment: What window are you wanting to open?

Comment: My idea was to open a window which I can edit in the Storyboard.

Comment: If you are talking about a window in your application, **NSWindow** has methods to create and show windows, but you would need to edit your post with more information (such a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) about what you are having problems with to get something more specific.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Next time I edit my post with mot informations! Thanks

Comment: I think I asked the exact same question as you about 5 years ago when I was 14. You should really check out SwiftUI. If you are interested in making GUI applications, SwiftUI is very easy to learn with youtube videos and is WAYY easier than applescript with XCode